# Как задать адрес ячейки данных в EEPROM для AVR микроконтроллера

Tags: c, avr, atmel-studio

Как расположить данные в EEPROM микроконтроллера ATmega по конкретным адресам? Если написать в Atmel Studio следующий код

```
char EEMEM version[] = { "1.0.0" };
int EEMEM state = 123;
```

то компилятор расположит `version` по адресу 0, а `state` вслед за `version`. В этом случае я могу обращаться к памяти EEPROM только по имени переменных, т.к. при изменении размера данных в `version` адрес `state` сместится, а мне необходимо обратиться по адресу. Плюс этого кода в том, что при сборке проекта сгенерируется файл `project_name.eep`, который можно зашить в микроконтроллер.

Есть ли возможность задать конкретный адрес в области EEPROM для хранения переменной?

Comment: если там под капотом `avr-gcc`, то «нормального» способа похоже нет: или вручную читать/писать значения, или для каждой переменной/структуры объявлять свою секцию и пихать переменные в неё...

Comment: а на практике просто собери это в структуру и сделай `version` фиксированного размера...